# Why not working col-sm-6 for IE7+

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-7

I have this sample:

[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNvNrL)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    asdad
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">asdsa</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">asdsa</div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">asdsa</div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Please test this example internet explore 7 and you'll see it's not working.

Can you please helps me solve this problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 dropped support for Internet Explorer 7.

> Bootstrap 3 uses the box-sizing property for layouts which is not
>   natively supported by IE7. The polyfill 'boxsizing.htc' is required:
>   [https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill](http://Bootstrap%203%20uses%20the%20box-sizing%20property%20for%20layouts%20which%20is%20not%20natively%20supported%20by%20IE7.%20The%20polyfill%20'boxsizing.htc'%20is%20required:%20https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill).

Whole thing is described well at: https://github.com/coliff/bootstrap-ie7